# Convert list values into dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have this output from an analysis

```
[2008 'Rajasthan Royals']
[2009 'Deccan Chargers']
[2010 'Chennai Super Kings']
[2011 'Chennai Super Kings']
[2012 'Kolkata Knight Riders']
[2013 'Mumbai Indians']
[2014 'Kolkata Knight Riders']
[2015 'Mumbai Indians']
```

I'm trying to have two values (*i.e.* `year` and `team name`) into a Pandas dataframe into two separate columns.

That is, for example from the above output - `2008` in one column and `'Rajasthan Royal'` in another column, and likewise for others.

Comment: what did you try? you can append into a single list and pass under `pd.DataFrame()`

Comment: How did you get this output? Can you paste the code that generated this?

Comment: for i in range(2008,2017):
    df=((matches[matches['season']==i]).iloc[-1]) 
    print(df[[1,10]].values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea could be to put your data in a `numpy` matrix, then transpose it, so that the first row is the `'Year'` row and the second one is the `'TeamName'` row:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[2008, 'Rajasthan Royals'],
                 [2009, 'Deccan Chargers'],
                 [2010, 'Chennai Super Kings'],
                 [2011, 'Chennai Super Kings'],
                 [2012, 'Kolkata Knight Riders'],
                 [2013, 'Mumbai Indians'],
                 [2014, 'Kolkata Knight Riders'],
                 [2015, 'Mumbai Indians']])

df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': data.T[0].astype(int),
                   'TeamName': data.T[1]})
```

Output:

```
   Year               TeamName
0  2008       Rajasthan Royals
1  2009        Deccan Chargers
2  2010    Chennai Super Kings
3  2011    Chennai Super Kings
4  2012  Kolkata Knight Riders
5  2013         Mumbai Indians
6  2014  Kolkata Knight Riders
7  2015         Mumbai Indians
```